# Mocha: How to assert after an event?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, johnny-five

I'm working with Electron and Johnny-Five to process some data I read with my Arduino Mega 2560 and I'm having some trouble testing my Arduino's connection.

This is the method I want to test (ignore the awful signature):

```
export let board: Board | null = null;

export function setArduinoBoard(f: (num: number, ...etc: any[]) => void, num: number, ...etc: any[]) {
    if (board == null)
        board = new Board({...});

    board = board.on("ready", () => f(num, etc));
}
```

And this is my test:

```
describe.only("setArduinoBoard()", function() {
    it("can communicate with the Arduino device", function(done) {
        const f = (num: number) => console.log(num);
        const spy = sinon.spy(f);
        setArduinoBoard(f, 0);
        assert(spy.called);
        done();
    });
});
```

What I want is for the assertion to wait until the function has been called. And I know it's called eventually because the console outputs 0 but it's only after the assertion fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach would be moving the `done` callback into the event handler. In this way, the test will wait until the callback is called. If the `ready` event is not fired, the callback won't be called and the test will timeout with an error after 2 seconds.

This means that you don't need to explicitly assert that the event `f` is called, and in fact, you don't event need to spy on it.

```
    it("can communicate with the Arduino device", function(done) {
        const f = (num: number) => {
            console.log(num);
            done();
        };
        setArduinoBoard(f, 0);
    });
```

If you need to assert something *after* the `ready` event has fired, you can add an assertion in the event handler and use a `catch` block to capture exceptions and pass them to the `done` callback.

```
    it("can communicate with the Arduino device", function(done) {
        const f = (num: number) => {
            try {
                assert.equal(num, 0);
                done();
                return;
            } catch (err) {
                done(err);
            }
        };
        setArduinoBoard(f, 0);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much GOTO 0! I ended up using the first solution you proposed and it worked just fine :)